# navigator.share undefined in Chrome for Android 83?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, web, share

I'm trying to use the Share API, but `navigator.share` is undefined.

I'm using Chrome for Android v83 and I've tested and got the same results on Chrome for Android beta v84.

`componentDidMount() {
    alert(navigator.share)
}`

[image]

Comment: FWIW, this was working yesterday :/

Answer (score 1):

`Navigator.share()` is available only on [secure contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share

Comment: According to the docs, localhost is considered Secure. But I'm also trying with ngrok over https and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`Navigator.share()` only works on HTTPS and localhost.

> Secure context This feature is available only in secure contexts
> (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.

Read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share